# Why does `\n` flush std::cout?

Tags: c++

I'm new to *C++*  and as far as I know that using escape sequence `'\n'` will not flush the output buffer (as it happens when using `endl`), but in my case when debugging the following program using F11 (step into) under qt-creator on *Ubuntu 14.04*, the output of the function (which is `5`) is directly being printed to the console.

```
#include <iostream>

void printValue(int nValue)
{
    std::cout << nValue << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    printValue(5);
    return 0;
}
```

When I removed the `'\n'` from the output in line no. 5, the output postponed till the end of the execution.

- Why is this?

Comment: See the libc functions: setbuf and setlinebuf.  setlinebuf is the implicit default for stdout/stderr [aka std::cout/std::cerr] for programs when they start up.  For streams you open yourself, they're given a default buffer size and the buffer must fill before it's flushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `endl` will cause a flush, but that doesn't mean the buffer can't decide to flush itself for other reasons. See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl), particularly this:

> In many implementations, standard output is line-buffered, and writing '\n' causes a flush anyway

Answer (score 2):

The time of flushing is not defined by the standard, so the stream can flush at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually implementation dependent, if `'\n'` seen in the `std::ostream` triggers flushing.

The enforced and safe method is to use `std::endl`.